# How to move only certain columns in row using sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want only certain columns to move based on a condition (saying "leased"), and not the whole row. I still want the entire row on the old sheet to be deleted, but only columns A-J to to be pasted over to the other sheet. Heres the current code

```
function onEdit(e) {
// edited sheet
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var s_name = s.getName();

// edited range
var range = e.range;
var value = range.getValue();
var row = range.getRow();
var column = range.getColumn();

// tabs that trigger moving rows
var tabs = [
'WPG Portfolio (Alex)',
'Walls & Syndicate Portfolio (Melissa)'
]

// check edited sheet
if(tabs.indexOf(s_name) > -1) {

// check edited column
if(column == 2) {

// check edited value
if(value == 'Leased') {

// master sheet
var s_master = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Leased Unit Data');
var last_row = s_master.getSheetValues(1, 1, s_master.getMaxRows(), 1).findIndex(x => x[0] == '');

// move row
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn()).moveTo(
s_master.getRange(last_row+1, 1, 1, s.getLastColumn())
)

// delete empty row from source sheet
s.deleteRow(row);
```

Comment: Change `s.getLastColumn` to 10.

Comment: @norie when I change that the function stops working